# felix exthttpservice set session path for cookies

Tags: java, jetty, osgi, apache-felix

I have a webapplication that I am running in Felix osgi container.  I am using jetty as the implementation for the extHttpService.  Currently it is writing the cookies to the '/' root path.  I would like to change this as it is causing conflicts with other web applications.  Looking at jetty documentation it appears I need to set the following property.

org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionPath

However, I am unable to find a way to set this using the ExtHttpService via osgi.  I have tried creating a jetty.xml file, adding this to the config.properties, and setting it as a property in the call to register my servlet.

Does anyone know how to set this?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up patching the source for my current implementation, but on the mailing lists [here](http://old.nabble.com/ExtHttpService-cookie-path-td32768063.html#a32776325), a patch has been submitted that should allow this to be configurable.